# No such command: pip when installing websocket library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to install `websocket` on my Centos Server

running this command

```
yum pip install websocket
```

getting error :

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks No such command: pip.
> Please use /bin/yum --help

when i execute : `pip3 --version`

```
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

any solution to install `websocket` as a root user

Comment: Maybe without `yum` at the beginning?

Comment: @KlausD. getting this error `bash: pip: command not found` after removing yum

Answer (score 1):

`pip` is a package manager for Python packages and not a part of `yum`. You can install packages using pip as below:

`pip install websocket`

if above command not working, try with `pip3`:

`pip3 install websocket`

Running `pip install` under root permissions is not safe. You can use virtual environment. But if you want to run it as root you can add `sudo` at the beginning of the command(s):

`sudo pip install websocket`

or

`sudo pip3 install websocket`